# Controlled input in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I am a newbie and recently learned about controlled input in React. Apparently one has to bind the function within the event handler that belongs to the component. Why?

```
class ControlledInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: ''
    };
    // binding in the constructor
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
 
  }
  // what the function does
   handleChange(event){
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    })
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value = {this.state.input} 
        
        {//binding within the component}
       <input onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
       </input>
       {//why}        
        <h4>Controlled Input:</h4>
        <p>{this.state.input}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Sorry for bothering you

Comment: The `.bind(this)` in the JSX is unnecessary. It has already been bound to `this` in the constructor, no need to do it again. The reason it's done at all is because otherwise `this` won't refer to the class instance. Another common solution is to make it an arrow function. There are several other good answers out there that explain in detail.

Comment: Where are you learning this? Seems like an outdated tutorial

Comment: ^ Also a good point. With ES6 binding is rarely required in React now. Plus with hooks, functional components have mostly replaced class based ones.

Comment: The bind(this) in javascript is because you pass the current instance of your component  tu use in in the method. If you don't add the bind, this will be the reference of the html element ( here the input ). So because of that, you can't access to your state. Bind is mandatory in class component